# Why is there an X Axis label glitch when animating a Date based Bar chart using Swift Charts?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm building a Bar chart using Swift Charts. The chart displays daily totals for a given week. I'm seeing a glitch when transitioning between consecutive weeks, where the first X axis label does not animate correctly and remains visible a bit more than expected.

This is a code example, that reproduces the issue. In this example, I added a button that just toggles between the current and the previous week, with an animation.

```swift
import Charts
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DailyTotal: Identifiable {
    let date: Date
    let value: Double
    
    var id: Date { date }
}

struct ChartView: View {
    @State private var displayCurrentWeek = true
    @State private var totals = Self.currentWeekTotals
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(totals) { total in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Day", total.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Total", total.value)
                )
            }
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) { _ in
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(), centered: true)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            
            Button("Toggle Week") {
                withAnimation {
                    displayCurrentWeek.toggle()
                    totals = displayCurrentWeek ? Self.currentWeekTotals : Self.previousWeekTotals
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let dayDuration: TimeInterval = 24 * 3600

extension ChartView {
    static let previousWeekTotals = [
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -13 * dayDuration), value: 10),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -12 * dayDuration), value: 10),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -11 * dayDuration), value: 25),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -10 * dayDuration), value: 20),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -09 * dayDuration), value: 5),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -08 * dayDuration), value: 10),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -07 * dayDuration), value: 5),
    ]
    
    static let currentWeekTotals = [
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -6 * dayDuration), value: 20),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -5 * dayDuration), value: 15),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -4 * dayDuration), value: 5),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -3 * dayDuration), value: 10),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -2 * dayDuration), value: 20),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -1 * dayDuration), value: 15),
        DailyTotal(date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -0 * dayDuration), value: 10),
    ]
}

struct ChartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChartView()
            .padding()
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

This is the preview for the above code, you can see that 'Tue' or 'Wed' labels glitch upon pressing the toggle button.

[image]

This seems like an issue with Swift Charts, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I also noticed the issue is *not present* if I don't customise the X axis, but the default setting is not acceptable for my design.

Thanks!